# NSOperation operationDidFinish with errors, add operation to queue again

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, nsoperation

I'm subclassing a `GroupOperation` and would like to run it again if it fails and the amount of attempts is less than 5. I also have a `delayOperation` to delay it by 3 seconds. I can't get this to work however, this is what I have so far:

`self.conversation` is an Object.

`produceConversationOperation()` returns a backgroundOperation

```
override func operationDidFinish(operation: NSOperation, withErrors errors: [NSError]) {  
    if let _ = errors.first {  
       if let _ = operation as? BackgroundOperation {  
            context.performBlockAndWait({ () -> Void in  
                self.conversation.retryCountValue++  

                if self.conversation.retryCountValue < 5 {  

                    let postConversationOperation = self.produceConversationOperation()  
                    let delayOperation = DelayOperation(interval: 3)  

                    postConversationOperation.addDependency(delayOperation)  

                    self.produceOperation(delayOperation)  
                    self.produceOperation(postConversationOperation)  
                }  
                else {  
                    self.conversation.retryCountValue = 0  
                }  

                self.saveContext()  
            })  
        }  
    }  
}
```

For some reason the operation isn't running again after the first failure. I have a feeling the issue is with the `self.produceOperation` method but I have no idea what.
There have been a few solutions to similar questions but I haven't found anything that has helped.

Thanks

Comment: how would I create a new NSOperation object and add it to the queue from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit late to answer this, but you might want to check out using `RetryOperation` from http://github.com/danthorpe/Operations which supports many of these issues:

1. max count of retries
2. customisable delay (with a wait strategy if you need random/exponential/etc)
3. it accepts a `GeneratorType` of the operation
4. it accepts a "retry handler" trailing closure which allows the consumer to "tweak" the next instance of the operation which will be retried.

To answer this question a bit more concretely though, and without knowing for sure what `produceOperation()` is doing, I would hazard a guess that it is not actually creating a fresh new instance, but in some way is returning the original operation.

Comment: Thanks @DanielThorpe will check it out

Comment: Hey @DanielThorpe, Thanks so much for the link, I'm incorporating it into my project. I'm just struggling to understand the delay, Generator and retry parameter, could you explain that to me please. For the Generator type, i'm assuming that would be an instance of my operation that I want to retry, the other 2 i'm not sure what to pass in as parameters. I don't really need a retry block but can't pass nil to it. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel.Thorpe any examples?

Comment: @mrcurious - I've answered a question here which is related: https://github.com/ProcedureKit/ProcedureKit/issues/414